# R Shiny: Create In-App Tutorials using Modals/Popups

Tags: r, shiny

Are there any pre-fabricated packages or a walk-through on how to create a tutorial in a shiny app that a user clicks through?

For example, when a user navigates to my shiny app, I would like them to first see a popup that says, "Welcome to my app! Would you like to walk through a quick tutorial?" If the user says "Yes", the tutorial will then highlight different buttons and aspects of an app with popups (modals) that the user will click "next" until the end of the tutorial.

I feel like I have seen this somewhere before, but I cannot seem to find any resources. Has anybody done anything like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wrapper for the Javascript [IntroJS](https://introjs.com/) package for R: `[RIntrojs][2]`. It is available on CRAN and an example can be seen here: https://carlganz.shinyapps.io/rintrojsexample/